# A cry boy / A crying boy

Tags: idioms, colloquial-language, idiomatic-language

1. You are a cry boy now.
2. You are a crying boy now.

What does the each sentence mean? When would you choose each form to mean what?

Comment: There's the idiomatic [***crybaby***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/crybaby) (or ***cry-baby***, but not usually written as two completely separate words), used to mean *a person, especially a child, who cries readily for very little reason.* But ***cryboy, cry-boy*** has no currency. Your second suggestion is grammatically valid, but not something native speakers would normally say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first is incorrect. You wouldn't hear someone say "cry boy". You can say "cry baby". This is a slightly rude (but not vulgar) way to say that someone is overly emotional and dramatic, and that they cry a lot.

The second sentence is correct. It means "you are a boy that is crying right now." However, you wouldn't hear people say it very often. There's not really any reason to tell a boy that is crying that he is a a boy that is crying. I'm sure he already knows.

Comment: Saying *crybaby* to a small child is OK, but for older children (say by school age) and outside of the family can be considered cruel and often occurs related to bullying.